# CSS in table column (td): Align right in but move to the left with padding

Tags: css, html-table, padding

I have to display numbers in an html-table and prefer to align them to the right, but the numbers need to be placed at the left of the cell like this:

```
Header A  |Header B  |
 -1       |5000      |
  1       | -20      |
100       |   1      |
```

The width of the column is dynamic, the font is sth like Arial.
I cannot change anything in the html (div, colgroup,..), nor use Javascript, but only attach a CSS class to the td.

I tried to use `calc(100% - 25px)`, but unfortunately 100% is the width of the table and not of the column.

Please see my example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mwtL9cde/4/
(I put 50px padding there)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you can do is to use fixed widths for your cells, in combination with `padding-right` values that you get by trial-and-error as in the following snippet (also note `box-sizing: border-box` to include the padding in the fixed widths)

But of course that's not dynamic and won't adapt to other values automatically.

```css
table {
width: 400px;
}
td {
  width: 200px;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
td:first-child {
    padding-right: 122px;
    background-color: yellow;
}

td:nth-child(2) {
    padding-right: 162px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <colgroup span="2"></colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn">-280</td>
        <td class="secondColumn">100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn">100</td>
        <td class="secondColumn">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn">-1</td>
        <td class="secondColumn">200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="firstColumn">123412345</td>
        <td class="secondColumn">-280</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```